# How to correctly deploy a EAR file on Oracle Weblogic administrator console

Tags: java, maven, deployment, weblogic, ear

I have an `EAR` file that I have built from my existing `maven web application`. I want to deploy the same on the `Oracle Weblogic Server Administration Console`. To go ahead with that, I logged in to the weblogic conole on `http://localhost:7001/console` and went to the `deployments tab`. Previously, I had placed the `EAR` file in my `Oracle_Middleware\domain\mydomain\base\applications` folder. In the deployments section, on the console, I get to chose `myprojectname.ear` and when I select that I get an option to `install`. So after I install the same, and everything happens properly, how do I be access my `index.jsp` that was the first screen in my `web project`? I do find something when I expand `myprojectname`'s tree in the deployment tab-> select the `myprojectnameWAR` module-> go to the testing tab-> and under `test point` I see a URL that is present it. but when I click that URL to access it, the webpage that opens up says `Error 403--Forbidden`. Any help on how I can access the `index.jsp` on the administrator console?

**UPDATE-1**

I'd like to point out that I was trying to access the application using the URL `http://localhost:7001/projectnameEAR` and `http://localhost:7001/projectname` etc. But just to take a look at it, I tried importing the `EAR` file into a new workspace on eclipse too see if the `index.jsp` actually existed in the `EAR`. But when I import it, all I can see is the `WARModule snapshot` and the `JAR Module`. I expected the `index.jsp` to be there because I obtained the `EAR` file from an existing web application that had the `index.jsp`. Or perhaps, it is there but the `EAR` file does not allow me to see it? Please help regarding how to access the `index.jsp` page. 
Im in much need.

**UPDATE-2**

So after trying everything out, I created a blank maven project in eclipse, built `.war`, `.jar` and `.ear` modules out of it, added the `.jar` and the `.war` modules as dependencies to the `ear` project and ran a maven clean install through eclipse. Further, I took the `.ear` file and put it in the `applications` folder and ran the URL to access the `index.jsp` in the `war` module, placed at `src/main/webapp/` and it worked.

I went ahead and copy pasted the contents of my existing `maven project` (i.e. the `jsps`, the `js's`, to the same `src/main/webapp/` directory. I also took all my `packages` that contained my `java classes` and put them in the `warmodule/src/main/java` path. But now if I go to run my `index.jsp`, I get to see the UI but the `chrome debugger` shows me a `404 - Not found` error when I try to access any of the functionalities(button click etc.) of the page. Is it because I have probably put the classes in the wrong place?

My existing project consists of `packages` in the `existingproject/src/` path and all the other `jsps` and `js's` in the `existingproject/WebContent` path.

Could somebody help me with where exactly (at which `path` in which of the `modules`) should I be putting all of my content so that it is accessible properly?

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the question is. It sounds like you have managed to deploy the EAR file to the server, so now you just want to access your application, is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I believe I have deployed it. But, yes I dont know how to access the application basically. @ewanc

Comment: ok, so your server is likely to be listening for incoming requests on port 8080 unless you have changed it in the configuration. So the URL you should put in your browser to access it will be http://localhost:8080/<name of your EAR file>. You can set the final name of your EAR as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173316/maven-ear-plugin-rename-the-app

Comment: Ive tried that but that doesnt seem to work.. @ewanc

Comment: Is the final name set? Otherwise you would have to enter the full name of the maven EAR artifact in the URL

Comment: I haven't explicitly tried setting a name like you suggested above, but I have tried accessing it with the full maven artifactID given in the pom.xml. But that returns a 404 for me. :/ @ewanc

Comment: Hmm, that sounds strange. I don't have a maven environment set up here (I'm at work) but if nobody has found a solution for you by the time I get home I can check on my environment at home.

Comment: It would really help if you could. Please do take a look I'm in real desperation at work here @ewanc

Comment: I will definitely check this evening. In the meantime I suspect that the problem is related to a difference between the name you expect to access the resource and the name the server expects.

Comment: Also, please check my edit before you do! @ewanc

Comment: Are you sure the port is correct? It's normally 8080 or 8000 by default. The index.jsp should still be in the WAR file, the EAR just contains the WAR and JAR. It should know by default that your web resources are in the WAR.

Comment: Im assuming that the port is `7001` and isnt it that by default? For weblogic atleast..  However that is what I was assuming because the console is accessible at `http://loclahost:7001/console`. Hence. However I tried with `8080`. And got error 404. I tried `8000` and it said `This web page is not available ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.. Something to look at, probably? @ewanc

Comment: though the default on weblogic is 7001, as per the documentation.

Comment: The admin console is normally on its own port, so that it doesn't interfere with your deployed applications. Although, as I said, I don't know weblogic at all so I can't say for sure. I have an example of exactly what you are doing at home, only on JBoss. I'll post an answer with all the relevant configuration as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than filling up the comments I thought I would write this as an answer and update it as we go.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472580/deploying-war-on-jboss-as7). I posted this a while ago when I had a similar issue. Maybe it will help.

Also, here is [another link](https://ruleoftech.com/2014/using-the-weblogic-12c-maven-plug-in-for-deployment) about the weblogic maven plugin. It may be worth trying to use this. In my experience with JBoss I found it more reliable than trying to deploy using the admin console. If nothing else it should give more helpful error messages if there is a problem.

UPDATE:

Ok, so I had a look at my project and here is the relevant part of the EAR pom.xml

```
<modules>
  <webModule>
    <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
    <artifactId>traintrack-web</artifactId>
    <contextRoot>/TrainTrack</contextRoot>
  </webModule>
  <jarModule>
    <groupId>com.traintrack</groupId>
    <artifactId>traintrack-core</artifactId>
    <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
  </jarModule>
etc
</modules>
```

I get the feeling that the contextRoot attribute may be what you need to set. So in my case I would point my browser to `http://localhost:8080/TrainTrack`. The EAR will then be deployed in such a way that it knows anything with that context root is to be forwarded to the WAR.

Hope that helps, if not please post your pom.xml files and we can go over them, maybe in chat if that suits.

Comment: Appreciate you looking into it, I'm off from work as of now, it's the weekend. I will try adding the `<contextRoot>` tag and let you know if that helps. Many thanks! @ewanc

Comment: No problem at all, keep me posted on how you get on

Comment: should I be adding the `.war` module as well, in the `pom.xml` for the `.ear` module? Like `<warModule>.....</warModule>` also? @ewanc

Comment: if i add the webModule element, it gives me a cvc-complex-type.2.4.a error :/ @ewanc

Comment: Saw this, maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125538/eclipse-validation-error-deploying-ear-to-weblogic-cvc-complex-type-2-4c-expec

Comment: I left that method the way it was and tried a different approach! Check my update2 please! @ewanc

Comment: Sorry, still catching up. This link has a pretty good description of  the directory structure for maven web projects. http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/

Comment: Please take a look at this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131937/ear-file-not-being-able-to-find-java-classes-from-jar-module @ewanc

Comment: okay so in relation to the question I posted above, When i load the ear on the console i get `Servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer for servlet Jersey Web Application could not be loaded because the requested class was not found in the classpath ` any idea why? I know it has something to do with adding jersey-container-servlet-core jar but which module do I add it in?

Comment: Ah, that could be because a dependency is set as provided, but the ear doesn't know where to find it. I'm guessing this is included in the server, so you may need to set a dependency to this in the manifest for the ear.